Dollar signs and $\LaTeX$ indicators?
How do I make dollar signs be used as dollar signs rather than $\LaTeX$ indicators?
Here is an example post: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/11232/arbitrage-opportunities-in-foreign-exchange


In the text mode,  enclose the dollar sign with backticks to get $
In the math mode, $100\$$ will get you $100\$$ 

Hope this helps.


You can use backticks to produce code formatting. $\LaTeX$ is not interpreted within code blocks. However, this looks ugly. Do you really want to see figures rendered as $100 and $200? I don’t.
You can embrace the $\LaTeX$, and type your money amounts as $\$100$ and $\$200$, which render as $\$100$ and $\$200$, but I find that ugly too. I prefer numbers in running text to look like the rest of the text, using the same font rendering; furthermore, I would prefer not to use a heavy javascript library unnecessarily.
You can simply escape the dollar sign with a backslash, typing your money amounts as \$100 and \$200. This is certainly the simplest option, and probably also the best looking. It also renders faster, as it doesn’t invoke a large javascript library. The amounts render simply in running text as \$100 and \$200.
You can talk about euros instead. Alt Gr+4 will produce a € sign on my Irish keyboard.

